# Get json with jQuery mobile from localhost

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, localhost

I create a JSON object  with fisrtTest.php
The JSON is correct when I open this page with WampServer ..

But I cannot do a Ajax request :/ 
Why ? Cross domain policy ?

> ```
> $.getJSON('http://localhost/tests/fisrtTest.php',
>     success
> );
>
> function success(data) {
> }
> ```

This is for a mobile app with phonegap

Answer (score 0):

What is your error? Can you view JSON response in the firebug console?
Below is working code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ibutton").click(function() {
    alert("go");
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/tests/fisrtTest.php",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                crossDomain: true,
                jsonpCallback: "CallBackFunction"
            });
    });
});


function CallBackFunction(json){
// 
};
```

Comment: When I open http://localhost/tests/fisrtTest.php I can see the JSON : 
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}

But if I create a html page with your code. Nothing happens. Firebug only indicates some cordova problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ibutton").click(function() {
    alert("go");
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/tests/fisrtTest.php?callback=?",
                dataType: "json",
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function(data) {

                }
            });
    });
});
```

Well, this works but firebug gets an error :

SyntaxError: invalid label
{"jack":1,"gt":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}